# Flutter http List of objects body

Tags: flutter

This is as example how I can request a simple  body elements

```
var body = jsonEncode({

      "name":"username",
      "phone":"-",

    });
```

my problem is **How to do the same with this complex one ?**

```
"items" :[
  {
  "product_id" :9,
  "quantity" : 2,
  "price" : 20
  },
  {
  "product_id" : 10,
  "quantity" : 3 ,
    "price" : 20

  }
]
```

I have a `List<myObject>Objects` whick contains all the data

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http.get("url").then((response) {
      map = json.decode(response.body);
}
```